# Reactive extensions C# use Catch with anonymous source type

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Oversimplified example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ReactiveCatch() {
var source = new[] { new { i = 1 }, new { i = 0 } }.ToObservable();
var a = source
    .Do(x => { var j = 1 / x.i; })
    .Catch((Exception exc) => Observable.Empty(new { i = 0 }))
    .ToEnumerable()
    .ToArray();
Assert.AreEqual(new { i = 1 }, a[0]);
}
```

Is there a way to provide a generic handler to the `Catch` method, which will return an empty default IObservable?

Comment: But that's what your code already does? What's a problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this solution after carefully reading the comment.

```
  static class Mixin {
    public static IObservable<T> CatchAndStop<T>(this IObservable<T> source) 
      => source.Catch((Exception exc) => Observable.Empty<T>());
  }
  [TestClass]
  public class ReactiveExtensions {
    [TestMethod]
    public void ReactiveCatch() {
      var source = new[] { new { i = 1 }, new { i = 0 } }.ToObservable();
      var a = source
        .Do(x => { var j = 1 / x.i; })
        .CatchAndStop()
        .ToEnumerable()
        .ToArray();
      Assert.AreEqual(new { i = 1 }, a[0]);
    }
```

But what if I need to ***Catch*** an exception of specific type? Something like `.CatchAndStop<TimeoutException>()`.

`IObservable<TSource> Catch<TSource, TException>(...)` has two generic parameters. Both of them need to be inferred in order to not specify them.

A dummy `Func<T>` to the rescue.

```
  static class Mixin {
    public static IObservable<TSource> CatchAndStop<TSource>(
      this IObservable<TSource> source) => source.CatchAndStop(() => new Exception());

    public static IObservable<TSource> CatchAndStop<TSource, TException>(
      this IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TException> witness
      ) where TException : Exception
      => source.Catch((TException exc) => Observable.Empty<TSource>());
  }
  [TestClass]
  public class ReactiveExtensions {
    [TestMethod]
    public void ReactiveCatch() {
      var source = new[] { new { i = 1 }, new { i = 0 } }.ToObservable();
      var a = source
        .Do(x => { var j = 1 / x.i; })
        .CatchAndStop(() => new TimeoutException())
        .CatchAndStop()
        .ToEnumerable()
        .ToArray();
      Assert.AreEqual(new { i = 1 }, a[0]);
    }
```

`TSource` is inferred from the `IObservable<TSource>` source
`TException` will be inferred from the second parameter - **witness**, which serves purely as a holder for TException's generic parameter type.

Not ideal, but whatever works ...